# Are `.then` and `.catch` Promise handlers somehow paired and treated like `.then(resolutionHandler, rejectionHandler)`?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

When working with promises in JavaScript, we have a possibility to use `.then`, `.catch` and `.finally`. Each of these methods returns a new `Promise` object.

Using `.then` is pretty straightforward - we chain them. The use case for finally - is to put it at the end of the chain of `.then` and `.catch`. But

In the code below, as I understand, we initialize promise `p` which can resolve or reject. I could use `.then(resolutionHandler, rejectionHandler)`, which would be self-explanatory as it's only 1 `.then` "handler" with both handlers, but in case of sequencing `.then` and `.catch` instead of the latter approach-

**Are `.then` and `.catch` handlers somehow paired and treated like `.then(resolutionHandler, rejectionHandler)`? or something else is happening? **

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  reject("ups...");
});

p
  .then(data => {
    // this is success handler for Promise "p"
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Is this failure handler for Promise "p"?
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly. When you have `p.then(handleThen).catch(handleCatch)`, if `p` rejects, `handleCatch` will handle it. But `handleCatch` will *also* handle errors thrown by `handleThen`.

Although those sorts of errors are pretty unusual with if `handleThen` contains only synchronous code, if `handleThen` returns a Promise, `handleCatch` will be able to handle that Promise if it rejects.

```
<somePromiseChain>
  .catch(handleCatch);
```

will have the `handleCatch` handle any errors thrown anywhere in the above Promise chain.

In contrast, with `p.then(resolutionHandler, rejectionHandler)`, the `rejectionHandler` will **only** handle a rejection of `p`. It will completely ignore anything that occurs in `resolutionHandler`.

If the `resolutionHandler` is completely synchronous, doesn't return a Promise, and never throws (which is pretty common), then `.then(resolutionHandler, rejectionHandler)` is indeed equivalent to`.then(resolutionHandler).catch(rejectionHandler)`. But it's [usually a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289) to use `.then(..).catch(..)`.

With `p.then(success).catch(fail)`, the `.catch` is actually attached to the Promise returned by the `.then` - but if `p` rejects, the `.then`'s Promise rejects as well, with the same value as `p`'s rejection. It's not that the `catch` is attached directly to `p`, but it's attached to a `.then` which passes `p`'s rejection through.

Every `.then` / `.catch` is attached directly to the upper Promise it's called on, but sometimes that upper Promise passes through the value from *its* upper Promise unaltered. That is. `p.then(undefined, fail).then(success)` will run `success` if `p` resolves, with the intermediate `.then` passing the resolution through. With rejection, `p.then(success).catch(fail)` will run `fail` because the `.then(success)` passes the failure from `p` through unaltered.

Comment: So these are 2 completely different mechanisms and they are not resolved to same code by JS runtime. I may suspect that in case `p.then.catch` if `p` get's rejected, then first `.then` will be tested to see if there is `rejectionHandler`, it's not there in `.then.catch` case, so rejection propagates to the next handler (basically promise-return-value of first .`then` is rejected in this case), whatever this is `.then`, `.catch` or `.finally`... is this right? If yes, where is this written in JS documentation?

Comment: Yes, if there's `p.then(success, fail)`, the `fail` will handle errors from `p`, no matter what comes after the whole `.then`. With `p.then(success, fail)`, either `success` or `fail` will be entered into regardless. But `.then(success)` only runs if the upper Promise resolved, and `.catch(fail)` only runs if the upper Promise rejected.

Comment: You can see the specification on it [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen), but it's quite dense.

Comment: Another way of looking at it: `.catch(fail)` does the same thing as `.then(undefined, fail)`. If the upper Promise rejected, `fail` is entered, otherwise the fulfilled Promise passes through unaltered. Similarly, `.then(success)` is passed through if the upper Promise rejected.

Comment: An if `p` throws an `error` or `rejects` and we have the following code `p.then.catch`, this means `.catch` is attached to Promise returned by `.then`, right? This means that `.then` can't handle rejection of `p` will make return value of itself - Promise in rejected state. Yes? So `.catch` doesn't react upon `p` being rejected, but on `p.then` being rejected.

Comment: With `p.then(success).catch(fail)`, the `.catch` is actually attached to the Promise returned by the `.then` - but if `p` rejects, the `.then`'s Promise rejects as well, with the same value as `p`'s rejection. It's not that the `catch` is attached directly to `p`, but it's attached to a `.then` which passes `p`'s rejection through.

Comment: Please add your last comment to the body of your answer as this was the underlying thing I was asking about. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `catch` internally calls `reject`

As per [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

*The catch() method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only. It behaves the same as calling Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected) (in fact, calling obj.catch(onRejected) internally calls obj.then(undefined, onRejected)).*